# Node/Typescript running latest pg version causes issue with SSL setting to true: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, pg

I have an issue running current latest pg version (8.7.3) on my Node/Typescript server. The server is enforcing SSL connection to the PostgreSQL database.

I am getting following error:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure 
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:935:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone 
code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
```

Downgrading pg to version 7.12.1 will again clear it, however this is not the way to go in a long run.

My Pool settings are:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

console.log('[WORKER]: DB CONNECTION SSL =', process.env.DB_SSL)

const pool = new Pool({
  "user": process.env.DB_USER,
  "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
  "database": process.env.DB_NAME,
  "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  "port": process.env.DB_PORT ? parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) : 5432,
  "ssl": process.env.DB_SSL === 'true' ? true : false
});

export default pool;
```

which means that `"ssl": true`

I have read here on stackoverflow that people who experienced this issue resolved it reverting to older version of pg (7.12.1). But as I stated above, this is not a way to go in a long run.

I would be very happy to hear from someone who managed to resolve this.

Comment: what happens when you turn off ssl ? like, ```"ssl": false```

Comment: @Dusayanta Prasad if I delete that line or turn it off the db won't get connected

Comment: is your PostgresSQL configured with ssl and enabled ?